# How can one configure Angular2 with a custom index.html location?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-cli

I've created an Angular2 application integrated with ASP.NET and served by IIS. This application is to be used by multiple clients and they would like the ability to customize the look and feel of the application to fit their branding. I'm using some aspects of ASP.NET MVC5's framework to make this possible.

The application is working as expected for most things, but I have two big stumbling blocks utilizing the cli that I can't seem to figure out.

Here is the basic folder structure of the application(there are other files and directories, but I'm excluding them as I don't believe they are relevant to the question):

```
Solution.sln
Web
  Controllers
  dist
  Models
  src
  Views
    Shared
      _Layout.cshtml
  .angular-cli.json
  package.json
  Web.config
  Global.asax
```

The only relevant update that I've made to my `.angular-cli.json` file is that I changed the `{ apps: { index: '' } }` value to be `"../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` instead of the default `"index.html"`.

When I run `ng build` from within the `Web` directory, the application compiles and the correct `script` tags are placed in the `_Layout.cshtml` file right before the closing `body` tag as expected.

---

*I'm not sure if these problems stem from the same root cause. I assume they do which is why I've put both here, but if they seem to be separate questions, I can break them apart.*

---

**Issue 1**
If I run `ng build` multiple times, it doesn't remove and replace the `script` tags it creates in the `_Layout.cshtml` file as expected, but instead continues to append new script tags before the closing `body` tag. So if I run `ng build` twice in development mode, I'll get the same set of `script` tags in the file twice.

Any ideas as to what I would need to change to get the expected functionality back from `ng build`?

---

**Issue 2**
Now when I run `ng build --watch`, the build seems to end up in an endless loop. It continues packaging the assets over and over.

Any ideas as to what might be causing the infinite loop and how I can get `ng build --watch` to work properly with this setup?

---

I didn't have either of these issues with the `index.html` file, but unfortunately, I need to use the `_Layout.cshtml` file as my index file. I can create a custom `prebuild` npm task to clean up the script tags, but it doesn't seem like I should have to. I have not figured out a work around for the watch task issue.

---

**UPDATE**
As I suspected, this has nothing to do with the fact that it is an `*.cshtml` file, but rather due to the fact that the `apps/index` location is outside of the src folder.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `npm install @angular/cli`
2. `node_modules/.bin/ng new test-custom-index`
3. Move`test-custom-index/src/index.html` to `test-custom-index/index.html`
4. Update the `.angular-cli.json` so index property is `"index": "../index.html"` instead of "index": "index.html"
5. From the `test-custom-index` directory run `node_modules/.bin/ng build` two times consecutively and you will see the duplicate script entries in the `index.html` file.
   OR run `node_modules/.bin/ng build --watch` and watch it get caught in an infinite loop.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!**

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by making the angular index page a partial and loading into the razor layout.

In the cli config:

`"index": "index.cshtml",`

but that file is actually blank. Then, in a razor file that uses the layout you want:

```
@section scripts
{
    <base href="~/">
    @Html.Partial("~/js/dist/index.cshtml")
}
```

You could also just put that partial directly into the layout. The only gotcha with this is that if the `index.cshtml` lies outside your View folder you need to make it inherit from `MvcWebPage`, and the easiest way to do this is to copy the web.config file from your View folder into a folder one up from the `index.cshtml` file.

Comment: This is a great idea.  However I found that it always wanted to resolve the linked in js an css files from the root instead of from the dist folder.  Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but in the `js/dist/index.cshtml`, the `<script>` imports will use the config from the `angular-cli.json`, eg `"deployUrl": "js/dist/"`

Comment: Nice solution. Although I don't know how do you approach the typical scenario where generated index holds both a `<link ... />` node in `</head>` (for style) and a set of `<script ...></script>` nodes in `<body>` (for code), and you want to insert those two in separate places in your  Razor *_Layout.cshtml*.

Comment: When starting from an empty index, generated one has them all packed together: `<head><link ... /></head><script ...></script><script ...></script><script ...></script>`.

Comment: Correct, with the `--prod` switch the cli extracts the .css into a `<head></head>` tag. Using my solution the final `index.cshtml` will have two `<head></head>` tags, but still magically works (tested even on old IE versions). You don't need to put it in different parts of the `_Layout.cshtml` for it to work. Not sure what the implications of that are, but so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have a work around in place that I would like to share if others are experiencing the same issue.

**I would still like to know if there is a better way to approach this as it seems a bit hacky to me.**

At the same level as the `src` directory, I created a `build` directory. In it, I have two files:

**`prebuild.js`**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml');
var outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/_Layout.cshtml');

fs.readFile(inputFilePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/<\/app-faculty-profile>[\s\S]*<\/body>/g, '</app-faculty-profile>\n\r</body>');

  fs.writeFile(outputFilePath, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

**`postbuild.js`**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../dist/_Layout.cshtml');
var outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml');

fs.readFile(inputFilePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  fs.writeFile(outputFilePath, data, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Then in my `package.json` file I added a few scripts:

```
"ng": "ng",
"prebuild": "node build/prebuild.js",
"build": "ng build",
"postbuild": "node build/postbuild.js",
"watch": "npm run build && ng build --watch"
```

Now when I run `npm run watch` from the command line, it will execute the `build` script. By convention npm scripts will run the `prebuild` before it executes the `build` script and the `postbuild` script after. The `prebuild` script removes the script tags from and then copies the `_Layout.cshtml` file into the `src` directory. The `postbuild` script then copies the `_Layout.cshtml` file back into the location that ASP.NET is expecting it to be in. After all of this the npm script kicks off the `ng build` command with the `--watch` flag. This forces the angular build process to execute twice before the watch actually takes effect, but this is the only way I've been able to get this to work so far.

Comment: In [this GH issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2960#issuecomment-262705959) there's another approach that adds custom build steps to extract pieces from generated index.html and write them into Razor file

Answer (score 0):

@user917170

> The only gotcha with this is that if the index.cshtml lies outside
> your View folder you need to make it inherit from MvcWebPage, and the
> easiest way to do this is to copy the web.config file from your View
> folder into a folder one up from the index.cshtml file.

you can just add the line to the index.cshtml:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```